# css sprite image position

Tags: css, background-image, css-sprites

I need to use sprite image, instead of simple background image.
The background image was used at the **right center** position of < UL >:

```
  background-image: url(../images/breadcrumbs_3.jpg);
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

and now I need to add the specific sprite position (e.g. -48px 0px)

Is there a way to mark both positions:

background-**location**-position [right center] and background-**sprite**-position [-48px 0px] ?

Comment: background-position: -48px 0px;

change class name for different image + change to background position

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-position&preval=50%25%2050%25

Comment: if I use the sprite position, the image is displayed (by default) on the left side of the UL. and I want it on the right side :(

Comment: Maybe you need to share a jsfiddle of what you have. You will need to have your sprite in a `<span>` then position the span to the right. you need to use the `background-position` to find the right image in the sprite you want to display. Have you thought about using icon fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed by using pseudo element :

```
#breadcrumbs ul::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url("../images/sprite-icon.png");
    background-position: -48px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

- I get **right** using "after".
- I get **center** using "vertical-align"

I do prefer simpler solution  . . .